# How can I make a timer slower and slower until it stops?

Tags: vb.net

Can someone tell me what's wrong or what I need to add to make it run the way that I want? I need to make it slower, then slower again, then make it stop.

Heres what I have tried:

```
Dim A As Integer
If Timer.Interval = 1 Then
    A = Timer.Interval + 1000
    If Timer.Interval = 1000 Then
        Timer.Enabled = False
    End If
End If
```

I want to stop the timer after a specific time but I have button 1 and 2 its random and stop, if I push the button random it will select any on given list then if I push stop the selection of random is going stop delay like spinning wheel, the missing on my program is the delay selection after a seconds its like selecting random then it will slowly selecting then it will stop.

Here's the btnRandom.Click event handler:

```
Private Sub btnRandom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRandom.Click
    If lstList1.Items.Count <= 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Name must more than 1 to run the randomizer.", "Error Loading", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    Else
        txtName.Enabled = False
        btnRandom.Enabled = False
        btnAdd.Enabled = False
        btnRemove.Enabled = False
        btnStop.Enabled = True
        btnAdd.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
        btnRemove.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
        btnRandom.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64)
        If btnRandom.Enabled = False Then
            Timer2.Start()
            lstList1.ClearSelected()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And the Timer.Tick handler:

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If btnRandom.Enabled = True Then
        Timer2.Enabled = False
    End If
    If btnRandom.Enabled = False Then
        txtNameLabel.Text = lstList1.Items(Rnd() * (lstList1.Items.Count - 1))
        lstList1.SelectedItem = txtNameLabel.Text
        txtNameLabel.Text = lstList1.SelectedItem
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour].

Comment: Is `A` doing anything in this code? Possibly you want to check the Interval only.

Comment: I'm assuming you want two separate if statements, not a nested if statement. Also, no need for A as stated above.

Comment: sorry im doing something like this, I want to stop the timer after a specific time but i have button 1 and 2 its random and stop, if i push the button random it will select any on given list then if i push stop the selection of random is going stop delay like spinning wheel, the missing on my program is the delay selection after a seconds its like selecting random then it will slowly selecting then it will stop

Comment: i didn't indicate it on my code because i just need to make it stop after delay for a bit of seconds then stop that is the missing part, but overall my program is working just that part is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to decelerate then you need to multiply the speed by a constant less than one, which in this case is equivalent to increasing the display time interval by a constant greater than one.

So, you can start something at one speed, and then add a deceleration by changing the amount the interval is changed by.

Something like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim sw As Stopwatch
    Dim tim As Timer
    Dim intervalMultiplier As Double = 1.0
    Dim itemsToDisplay As List(Of String)
    Dim itemIndex As Integer = 0

    Private Sub tim_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' When intervalMultiplier > 1.0 the time between ticks will increase.
        tim.Interval = CInt(tim.Interval * intervalMultiplier)
        Label1.Text = itemsToDisplay(itemIndex)

        If tim.Interval >= 1000 Then
            tim.Stop()
        End If

        itemIndex = (itemIndex + 1) Mod itemsToDisplay.Count

    End Sub

    Private Sub StartTimer()
        If tim Is Nothing Then
            tim = New Timer()
            AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf tim_Tick
        End If

        If sw Is Nothing Then
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        Else
            sw.Restart()
        End If

        intervalMultiplier = 1.0
        tim.Interval = 100
        tim.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub bnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnStop.Click
        intervalMultiplier = 1.25

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRandom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRandom.Click
        ' Your code to disable buttons etc. goes here.

        StartTimer()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Set up some data for this example.
        itemsToDisplay = New List(Of String) From {"Capacitor", "Diode", "Inductor", "Resistor", "Transistor"}

    End Sub

End Class
```

[image: A form showing one item at a time out of several which updates at longer and longer intervals]

Comment: btw is it applicable in VB 2012?

Comment: @Ogirelc I have re-worked my answer in the light of being able to see enough of your code. It will work in older VB.NET versions, but do note that [VS2019 Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) is up-to-date and free (even using VS2017 would be  better experience than other older versions). Oh, and please do make sure to set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project and as the default for new projects, if you haven't had the chance to do that yet.

Comment: Wow you really did it thank you so much my work is done 